# How to insert text from a variable at current cursor position?

Tags: vimscript

I am writing a vim script, and I need to insert the contents of a string variable at the current cursor position. What is an appropriate way to do this?

```
let text = "Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet ..."
" How to insert text at current cursor position?
```

I know that `:read` can do something like this, but it is only applicable for inserting text that come from files, not text stored in variables.

Answer (score 9):

You can do a literal insert of register contents through [`:help i_CTRL-R_CTRL-R`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R_CTRL-R), combined with the *expression register* ([`:help quote=`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#quote%3D)) to reference the variable:

```
execute "normal! i\<C-r>\<C-r>=text\<CR>\<Esc>"
```

Note that newlines will appear as `^@`; if the variable does not contain any other special characters, you could switch to [`:help i_CTRL-R`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R), which *does* interpret the variable contents as types (and therefore inserts a newline, but would also interpret stuff like <kbd>Home</kbd> etc.)

If you know that the variable contents are just plain text (without any special control characters), you could also just append the variable contents as-is and conclude with `<Esc>`:

```
execute "normal! i" . text . "\<Esc>"
```

Or use the low-level [`setline()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#setline%28%29), splicing in the text at the cursor column via string manipulation:

```
let line = getline('.')
call setline('.', strpart(line, 0, col('.') - 1) . text . strpart(line, col('.') - 1))
```

Comment: I don't think you need `Esc` in `execute "normal! i" . text . "\<Esc>"` do you? At least if wrapped in a function.

Comment: @MaximKim: You can get away without it, but I prefer to be fully correct. This matters if, for example, you add another `:normal` later in that function.

Comment: It still works without explicit `Esc` though. fun! Test()
    let text = "Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet ..."
    exe 'normal a' . text
 normal gg
endfun

Comment: But the help shows example with `\<Esc>`, so consider me convinced :)

Comment: Does the first normal even need execute?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: For the double-quoting and special `\<CR>` notation. Yes, you could type `\<C-r>` as `^R` instead, but the Enter would be difficult I think.

Comment: Ah, for some reason I was thinking normal would interpret `<C-r>` like a mapping. Ofc. The enter would be done the same way, no problem. But this is cleaner.

Comment: if the value in `text` contains new lines, they show as `^@` in the file.

Answer (score 5):

You might go with `setline` function or simple:

```
let text = "Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet ..."
exe "normal! a" . text . "\<Esc>"
```

- `exe` (`:execute`) is to execute vimscript
- `normal! a` executes `a` command as you type in vim (append after cursor)
- `. text` then you concatenate your text with `normal a`. As you would type this text in vim after `a`.
- and `'\<Esc>` to exit insert mode.

Answer (score 2):

The following function emulates the behaviour of: <kbd>i</kbd> + insert text + <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

```
" Insert text at the current cursor position.
function! InsertText(text)
    let cur_line_num = line('.')
    let cur_col_num = col('.')
    let orig_line = getline('.')
    let modified_line =
        \ strpart(orig_line, 0, cur_col_num - 1)
        \ . a:text
        \ . strpart(orig_line, cur_col_num - 1)
    " Replace the current line with the modified line.
    call setline(cur_line_num, modified_line)
    " Place cursor on the last character of the inserted text.
    call cursor(cur_line_num, cur_col_num + strlen(a:text))
endfunction
```

Usage:

```
let text = "Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet ..."
call InsertText(text)
```

Documentation:

- [`setline()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#setline())
- [`setpos()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#setpos())