# How do I suppress beginning newline added by put()?

Tags: vimscript

I've got this simple function:

```
" generates a link in markdown using an extern script
function! WebLink()
    put =system('~/bin/taskwiki_helper.pl markdown_link_from_url')
endfunction
```

It works but inserts a blank line before inserting the text into the buffer. `:h put` didn't seem to offer any useful info on this. Is there a way to suppress the newline or is there a different function that does what I need?

Comment: I don't think `:put` will add a blank line... But just like the `p` Normal-mode command, `:put` will paste the contents of the register *after* the current line. Is that what you're seeing here? If so, maybe using `:put!` instead (which matches the behavior of the `P` command) is what you want? Or perhaps you want to replace the contents of the current line with the output of the external command? Please be more specific about the behavior you're seeing...

Comment: I want to insert the text from the output of the script at the current cursor location, not the next line.

Comment: Found this: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/28026/2021. But it's hard to believe there is not a built-in vim function to pull this off.

Comment: maybe `setline(line('.'), 'your string'))`

Comment: are you looking for `:exe ":norm! i\<c-r>=<variable>\<cr>"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
call setline('.', system('~/bin/taskwiki_helper.pl markdown_link_from_url'))
```

##### Edit

See caveats in the comments from @filbranden and also check out their answer!

Comment: You might want to mention that this is *replacing* the contents of the current line, rather than inserting text and leaving those contents unchanged. (It's possible that this is what the OP wanted, but it might be nice to make it more explicit.) You don't need the `line('.')` part, you can pass `'.'` as an `{lnum}` directly to `setline()` and it will set the contents of the current line.

Comment: There's also an issue with newlines in the output, which will show up in the line as `^@` (NUL characters). You might want to use `trim()` on the argument to remove the final newline before you use `setline()` on it. You might also run into trouble if `system()` returns more than one line of output, in which case the `^@`s in the middle will be preserved (and it's not as easy as a simple `trim()` to drop them...)

Comment: One option to handle multi-line output (and not worry with the last newline) is to use `systemlist()`, which returns a list of lines rather than one string with the multi-line contents. `setline()` can handle a list, but what it does is replace the current line and the next "n" lines ("n" depending on the number of lines in the output) with the contents of the list, which might be a problem if you don't necessarily care about the current line (which `setline()` will always override) but would like to preserve the contents of the following lines...

Comment: Thanks @filbranden for these points. I only very recently started to rely on vim's builtin functions, as opposed to a lot of difficult-to-decipher `execute 'normal!'` statements, when creating custom functions in my .vimrc. I'm not very expert on many of the issues you point out, so instead of trying to rehash your comments in my answer, I'll point people to them directly. (+1 for your answer).

Answer (score 4):

The `:put` Ex command will always work *linewise*, which is actually described in [`:help :put`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Aput):

> Put the text [from register x] after [line] (default current line).  This always works linewise, thus this command can be used to put a yanked block as new lines.

You can also follow the link to [`:help linewise`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#linewise) to understand what it means.

What you actually want, “insert the text from the output of the script at the current cursor location” as you described it, is what in Vim parlance means *characterwise* mode.

You can use the [`P`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#P) or `p` command to put the contents of the register, which will do what you want if the register contents are seen from Vim as *characterwise*. With the expression register (`=`), this will happen if the contents have no line break at the end. The contents of `system()` typically do have a line break at the end, but you can work around that with an extra call to `trim()` around it.

So you could put the contents of the `system()` call right at the cursor position with the following Normal-mode command:

```
"=trim(system('~/bin/taskwiki_helper.pl markdown_link_from_url'))<CR>P
```

(Where the `<CR>` is a press of the "Enter" key. The expression above works as is in an `nnoremap` if you want to use it.)

You can do the same in a function, but then you need to use `normal!` and also `:execute` to escape the `<CR>`, which means you need an extra escape of the `"` for the register reference:

```
" generates a link in markdown using an extern script
function! WebLink()
    execute "normal! \"=trim(system('~/bin/taskwiki_helper.pl markdown_link_from_url'))\rP"
endfunction
```

Another option, if you don't mind writing the output of `system()` to a register (which might actually affect the unnamed register, so clobber your next paste) is to use `setreg()`, which takes a third argument that can be `'c'` to *force* characterwise mode.

For example:

```
" generates a link in markdown using an extern script
function! WebLink()
    call setreg('w', trim(system('~/bin/taskwiki_helper.pl markdown_link_from_url')), 'c')
    normal! "wP
endfunction
```

Note that this will work characterwise even without the `trim()`, it will insert the output characterwise since the register contents will be forced that way. It will still preserve the final line break at the end of the contents, so maybe the `trim()` is still what you want...

There are some other variations on this theme, for example you can enter insert mode with `i` and then use `<C-R>` to enter a register expression and use the expression register (`=`) from there. Insert mode always inserts contents characterwise, so that's not a concern in that case either.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and tried many things like "can I change a line type register to character type?", "can I avoid the newline from input?" etc.

I found a very simple solution that doesn't require installing plugins or anything like that, although it is a bit hacky.

I my case I take input from an external command. Because the external command is interactive I can't use `:read` and thus I place the linewise content in the `"*` register.

I then have this key binding:

`nmap <leader>c <ESC>i<CR><ESC>:!refs<CR>"*PJkJ`

So basically, at cursor position, I:

- set `INSERT` mode
- insert a new line
- set `NORMAL` mode and run my external command, that copies output to pasteboard
- paste the register on the line above and join the three lines

I end up with the output from the external command at cursor location.